# Count users who down-voted questions but not answers, despite anonymisation of Votes table in SEDE?

Tags: support, down-votes, data-explorer

To gather some evidence prior to posting a feature request, I wanted to count the number of users who have down-voted at least one question but have never down-voted an answer. The intention is to find some evidence that people are reluctant to down-vote answers, but are happy to down-vote questions.

Based on the anonymity of the Votes table, this seems to be an impossible task. Before I give up entirely, does anyone have any suggestions of how to achieve this?

Alternatively, if I share the query I would run if votes weren't anonymised, could someone with access to the raw data run the query for me? Hopefully it's clear from the description that it wouldn't violate privacy.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to know if a user has downvoted a question. The only way to know if a user has downvoted an answer is to check the reputation tab on their profile, and look for *-2 downvote* entries.

Comment: @Stijn That data isn't exposed via SEDE, is it?

Comment: It isn't, and scraping would be impractical.

Comment: Not quite sure why my support request is attracting down-votes. Is that people trying to say "this isn't possible" or is my question somehow off-topic/unclear/lazy?

Comment: I was wrong earlier, the *-2 downvote* entries are for received downvotes, not given. So it's impossible.

Comment: @Duncan people probably don't like you try to mess with downvotes. Personally, seems like a valid support question, so +1.

Comment: I've had [some useful feedback](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2459982#2459982) from Balpha, so perhaps I'll work on asking the community team to run something for me.